# In TeamCity, can I run a command-line application for the duration of a build?

Tags: command-line, teamcity

I have a command-line application that I want to run in a build configuration for the duration of the build, then shut it down at the end when all other build steps have completed.

The application is best thought of as a stub server, which will have a client run against it, then report its results. After the tests, I shut down the server. That's the theory anyway.

What I'm finding is that running my stub server as a command line build step shuts down the stub server immediately before going to the next build step. Since the next build step depends on the server running, the whole thing fails.

I've also tried using the custom script option to run both tools one after another in the same step, but that results in the same thing: the server, launched on the first line, is shut down before invoking the second line of the script.

Is it possible to do what I'm asking in TeamCity? If so, how do I do it? Please list any possibilities, right up to creating a plugin (although the easier, the better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you can do that in a Nant script, have Teamcity run the script, look for spawn and the nantContrib waitforexit.

However I think you would be much better off creating a mock class that the client uses only when running the tests.  Instead of round tripping to the server during the build as that is can be a bit problematic, sometimes ports are closed, sometimes the server hangs from the last run, etc.  That way you can run the tests, make sure the code is doing the right thing when the mock returns whatever it needs to return etc.

Comment: I knew I could script it. Looks like there is no alternative. Thanks for clarifying.